# Average for a specific number with fixed increment in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assume I have the list below

```
array=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

I want to find average for the first element with increment 4 numbers.
For example, first average will be for the numbers `0, 4, 8, 12 = 6`

The second average will be for the numbers `1, 5, 9, 13 = 7`

 And so one, finally will have 4 numbers represents the averages.
I wrote
 
    `Av=[]
    mean =0
    array=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
    for i in range(len(array)):
     for n in 4:
        mean = array[n] +mean
        mean  = mean/4
        Av.append(mean)`

But it does not increment the loop.
Regards

Comment: The formatting and indentation of your code looks broken, please edit your post to fix it. _But it does not increment the loop._ What does that mean? Which part are you struggling with, specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [python slice operator](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html) instead of for loops.

```
av = []
array=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
for i in range(4):
    av.append(sum(array[i::4])/len(array[i::4]))
```

What this does:

The operation `[::4]` takes every 4th element. The operation `[i::4]` takes every 4th element, starting with the ith element.

The mean of a list is just the sum of its elements divided by its length.

Answer (score 1):

First in Python this is called a list instead of an array (I alway forget this to ;-))

I did write a function that could do the trick, and is flexible in the step size.
Here is my solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
my_list=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

def avg_steps(list_for_split_avg, step=1):
    avg_step=[]
    offset = 0
    while offset < step:
        location = offset
        count = 0
        sub_sum = 0
        while location < len(list_for_split_avg):
            count +=1
            sub_sum += list_for_split_avg[location]
            location += step
        avg_step.append(sub_sum/count)
        offset += 1
    return avg_step

print(avg_steps(my_list,4))
```

Hope this helps.